# Return all regex matches in list

Tags: python-3.x, regex

Trying to get all matches in my list in the correct form.
example:

```
import re

regex = re.compile(r'(\d{1,4})')
text = ['(261, 264)', '(458, 393)', '(960, 540)', '(542, 424)', '(541, 424)']
print(regex.findall(text[0]))
print(list(filter(regex.findall, text)))
```

outputs:

```
['261', '264']
['(261, 264)', '(458, 393)', '(960, 540)', '(542, 424)', '(541, 424)']
```

I'm trying to get the bottom part in the same format as the top (without the parenthesis or comma). Is this possible? I can't seem to get these functions to return all matches in my list (I want to make it in 1 line like the list(filter()) is if at all possible)

edit::
desired output:

```
['261', '264', '458', '393', '960', '540', '542', '424', '542', '424']
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you are expecting? It was not exactly clear to me.

You want your output to be:
`['261', '264']`
or
`['261', '264', '458', '393', '960', '540', '542', '424', '542', '424']`
?

Comment: Sorry yes, that second one

Comment: Ok, I've just posted my solution.

Obs: You have a typo in your desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

list comprehension that merges all matches (by iterating over all of them):

```
import re

regex = re.compile(r'(\d{1,4})')
text = ['(261, 264)', '(458, 393)', '(960, 540)', '(542, 424)', '(541, 424)']

print([x for t in text for x in regex.findall(t)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import re

regex = re.compile(r'(\d{1,4})')
text = ['(261, 264)', '(458, 393)', '(960, 540)', '(542, 424)', '(541, 424)']
print(regex.findall(text[0]))
print([elem for tup in map(regex.findall, text) for elem in tup])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

### Explaining

1. Find the matches per each element you have in the list (just like you did)

This will leave you with the following result:

```
[['261', '264'],
 ['458', '393'],
 ['960', '540'],
 ['542', '424'],
 ['541', '424']]
```

2. Flatten this list:

Which will leave you with the result you want

```
['261', '264', '458', '393', '960', '540', '542', '424', '541', '424']
```

### Final Code

```py
import itertools
import re

original_list =  ['(261, 264)', '(458, 393)', '(960, 540)', '(542, 424)', '(541, 424)']
regex =  re.compile(r"\d\d\d")


matches_per_element = [regex.findall(txt) for txt in original_list]
flattened_list = list(itertools.chain(*matches_per_element))


### Display the result
print(flattened_list)
>>> ['261', '264', '458', '393', '960', '540', '542', '424', '541', '424']
```